# UI wont update after using StateFlows and .collectAsState

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Expected Behavior: When the button is clicked, it should immediately update the text and color to reflect the new reward value.

Actual Behavior: When the button is clicked, it calls the functions to update the data and save it to Firestore. However, the UI is not updating until the screen is reloaded.

Tried Things: I've switched from LiveData to StateFlow but that did not solve it.

```
Repository:

var currentUser = MutableStateFlow<User?>(null)
        private set
fun updateCurrentUserFirestore() {
        val updatedUser = hashMapOf(
            "skipCoins" to currentUser.value?.skipCoins,
            "tasksDone" to currentUser.value?.tasksDone,
            "tasksSkipped" to currentUser.value?.tasksSkipped,
            "gamesWon" to currentUser.value?.gamesWon,
            "gamesLost" to currentUser.value?.gamesLost,
            "reward" to currentUser.value?.reward
        )
        firestore.collection("user").document(currentUser.value?.userId.toString())
            .set(updatedUser)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateCurrentUserFirebase:success")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.w(TAG, "updateCurrentUserFirebase:failure", it)
            }
    }

    fun changeRewardCurrentUser() {
        if (currentUser.value?.reward == "Joke") {
            currentUser.value.let {
                if (it != null) {
                    currentUser.value = User(
                        userId = it.userId,
                        skipCoins = it.skipCoins,
                        tasksDone = it.tasksDone,
                        tasksSkipped = it.tasksSkipped,
                        gamesWon = it.gamesWon,
                        gamesLost = it.gamesLost,
                        reward = if (it.reward == "Joke") "Bored" else "Joke"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
fun updateCurrentUser(uid: String) {
        firestore.collection("user").document(uid)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                currentUser.value = User(
                    userId = result.id,
                    skipCoins = result.data?.get("skipCoins").toString().toLong(),
                    tasksDone = result.data?.get("tasksDone").toString().toLong(),
                    tasksSkipped = result.data?.get("tasksSkipped").toString().toLong(),
                    gamesWon = result.data?.get("gamesWon").toString().toLong(),
                    gamesLost = result.data?.get("gamesLost").toString().toLong(),
                    reward = result.data?.get("reward").toString()
                )
                Log.d(TAG, "updateCurrentUserLocal:success")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.w(TAG, "updateCurrentUserLocal:failure", it)
            }
    }
```

```
ViewModel:

val currentUser: StateFlow<User?> = repository.currentUser
fun updateCurrentUserFirestore() {
        repository.updateCurrentUserFirestore()
    }

    fun changeRewardCurrentUser() {
        repository.changeRewardCurrentUser()
    }
```

```
Composable:

val user by viewModel.currentUser.collectAsState()
Button(
                        shape = ShapeDefaults.ExtraSmall,
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.changeRewardCurrentUser()
                            viewModel.updateCurrentUserFirestore()
                        },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            containerColor = if (user?.reward == "Joke") Purple40 else Orange80,
                            contentColor = if (user?.reward == "Joke") Orange80 else Purple40
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier.width(
                            calcDp(
                                percentage = 0.25f,
                                dimension = Dimension.Width
                            )
                        )
                    ) {
                        user?.let { Text(text = it.reward) }
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us how are you reading the data from Firestore? Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: I added the reading part into my question and will take a look at the repo you sent, thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()), you're only reading the data once. This means that after you get the data if something on the server is changed, you aren't notified about that change. What you are looking for is to get [real-time updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). This means that each time something on the server changes, you are notified in real-time.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But since i update the firebase user from my local currentUser after changes shouldnt the ui update the changes in realtime? I only load the user from firebase once after login and then update this user with my local user

Comment: Without attaching a real-time listener, you cannot get changed data. So I recommend you use Kotlin Flow, and provide real-time updates to the UI. Here is a [concrete](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firestorecleanarchitecture/data/repository/BooksRepositoryImpl.kt) example.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my problem yay, here the solution:

Add this in graddle
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")

And use .collectAsStateWithLifecycle instead of .collectAsState in the Composable

Comment: I really cannot see how you can get real-time updates without using a persistent listener. Can you please explain how this solution solves the problem?

Comment: I think it works since i only load the user once from firebase. After that i use the local currentUser var and upload it to firebase after changes. Since i work only with this local var i dont need the real time update. My solution now allowed me to display the changes in the ui in realtime instead of after reloading the screen 

Honestly i dont know if this is the cleanest way since this is my first app but he at least it works now